# mysql select from subquery

Tags: mysql, select, nested

I have a db with multiple tables , for instance: 

`| usage_777771000034915 |
| usage_777771000034916 |
| usage_777771000034918 |
| usage_777771000034923 |
| usage_777771000034926 |
| usage_777771000034928 |
+-----------------------+
7036 rows in set (0.11 sec)`

Now ; i Want to select a particular field for each table ; 
I think a

```
SELECT field FROM (inner SELECT ...) should work.
```

I already got the inner SELECT working like:

`SELECT TABLE_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = 'cdba_cpe_history' and TABLE_NAME like 'usage_%'`

But ; can not get the completed nested query to work.
Any idea would be great:
So far I have:

`select cdba_cpe_history.x.dlbytes  from (SELECT TABLE_NAME  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE table_schema = 'cdba_cpe_history' and TABLE_NAME like 'usage_%') AS x;`

But it yields "unknow colum"
Regards.

Comment: Could you please exemplify?

Comment: do you want have 1 resultset with the rows from all selected teables ?

Comment: @scaisEdge - you cant give the tablename via select. the only way is to store the query in a varable and execute it with prpared statement

Comment: @scaisEdge - Try this, it never work, you cant refer the tablename from a subselect  - **Select x.* from (select 'aTableName' ) as x;**  = **1064 syntax error**

Comment: Hi , scaisEdge, could you provide an example for this ?

Comment: Hi Bernd , yes I want ti have a result set . All the tables are exactly the same;
I would like for instance to write a query like:
select firmware from "all_tables".